R2DBC issue with Micronaut
I am currently using R2DBC connector with Postgresql within a Micronaut application. Although my configuration seems good and everything is working fine when I perform a request, I have always the same error message at each request on the database:

[reactor-tcp-epoll-1] ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped
io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$PostgresConnectionClosedException: Connection closed

Here is my dependencies related to database connection:
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-r2dbc")
    implementation("io.micronaut.r2dbc:micronaut-r2dbc-core")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql")

And here my configuration for database access (application.yml file)
r2dbc:
    datasources:
        default:
          url: r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/backend
          username: xxx
          password: xxx

I have not found anything on the internet regarding this issue. If anybody has any clue on this topic, it would be very helpful ! Thx.

Isn't the postgres driver "io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql"
